# Data txt files work when read in iPhone simulator, but do not work on iPhone device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have two text files (.txt) that are in the Documents directory of the Bundle for my project.  The files load and work fine when I run the project on the iPhone Simulator in xCode, however the when I run the same project in xCode using my iPhone nothing gets loaded.  I have checked and the files don't even exist in the file directory when the iPhone is selected to run the project. 
Here is the code. Again this works fine and the file exists running under iPhone simulator in xCode, but the file does NOT exist when I run it using my iPhone as the device.

```
NSArray *arrayPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:CURRENTPUZZLENUMBERFILE];

NSLog(@"Path = %@", path);  // for debugging
bool fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
NSLog(@"File exists: %d", fileExists);   // for debugging
```

Comment: When an app is freshly installed, it's documents directory is empty, so it's no surprise that the file isn't there on the device.  The surprise is that it's on the simulator.  Either through the mac os file system, or some prior build of the app must have written a file there.  (note the docs directory is different from your app bundle).

Answer (score 1):

Grab the file this way then you can copy it to your doc dir if you wish

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:CURRENTPUZZLENUMBERFILE ofType:@"txt"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much - that did it, problem solved. One last thing, where in the documentation can I read about this?  Thanks again.

Comment: Try this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html